# What is equivalent iOS API for something like .NET cookie container

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

I'm new to mac development, i want to know the equivalent iOS API for .NET cookie container.

.NET cookie container is something like stores the cookies from an initial HTTP request and then sends same cookies in subsequent requests. Which exactly behaves like browser, but it is not a browser component.

Comment: .NET cookie container is not persistence mechanism. The main job of it is extracts and stores the cookies supplied by website in its response and includes and sends back the cookies on subsequent requests.

in .NET we make web requests using HTTPRequest class, when we attach CookieContainer to HTTPRequest class, above mentioned functionality handled automatically without putting additional efforts.

If iOS does not have such API/Libraries/Classes, guide me in retrieving Cookie info from HTTP response headers. In short, how to manipulate HTTP request/responses in iSO 4?

Answer (score 0):

I edited your question to make it a bit clearer what you're asking.

For HTTP client work on iOS, I use ASIHTTPRequest, a 3rd party library that wraps the built-in HTTP client API, and which does support cookies.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/

Comment: .NET cookie container is not persistence mechanism. The main job of it is extracts and stores the cookies supplied by website in its response and includes and sends back the cookies on subsequent requests.

in .NET we make web requests using HTTPRequest class, when we attach CookieContainer to HTTPRequest class, above mentioned functionality handled automatically without putting additional efforts.

If iOS does not have such API/Libraries/Classes, guide me in retrieving Cookie info from HTTP response headers. In short, how to manipulate HTTP request/responses in iSO 4?